# CSS sidebar overlapping

Tags: html, css

Website side bar is overlapping after footer I want to hide it before footer
following is the CSS for sidebar issue that I am facing.

apart from this

```
body {
overflow-x: hidden;
/* Prevent scroll on narrow devices */
}
.offcanvas-collapse {
 position: fixed;
 overflow-y: auto;
 visibility: visible;
 background-color: #7C00FF;
 transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 transition-duration: .3s;
 transition-property: width, visibility;
 width: 0;
 flex: 1;
 height: 100%;
  z-index: 99999;
  padding-top: 20px;
  }
```

I don't want to make it small with height I want it should be hidden after footer. I have used z-index in footer but it's not stopping its overlapping after footer.

See the image added below do I need to edit java script or it will work with CSS only the website is in aspx

It behaves same in mobile but I think it will solve the issue if desktop issue is solved

[image: issue image]

Comment: Can you replicate your error on a fiddle?

Comment: Can you format you question to run the code and reproduce the issue. 
https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: please add more css and the html tag structure. (some content is desirable!)